# How to fetch the Document/Assignment manager name using @ formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a view in which I need to fetch the document manager name but not the hierarchical name. I need to fetch the last name and the first name. I have used the @Name function but I'm not sure how to use it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Many people are under the impression that `@Name([G];theName)` will give the first name and `@Name([S];theName)` will give the last name -- because that's what the [Lotus documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/79efa449711fbee985256c54004c0b92?OpenDocument) says. That's actually true, but it only ever worked for hierarchical names that came in messages received via the old Lotus X.400 gateway, which could include G and S components (e.g., CN=first last/G=first/S=last/OU=ou1/O=org/C=US).

The best you can do with @Name for an ordinary Notes/Domino user is to use @`Name([CN];theName)`, as suggested by @Mike Zens, and then if you need to separate first and last names you can use @Left and @Right. Unfortunately, there's no perfect way to do this because the CN could look like this: "Mary Ann Jones" where the first name might be "Mary" or it might be "Mary Ann". (And I've actually been confronted by a user with that name who was angry that a piece of software I was supporting made the assumption that "Ann" was her middle name!)  Or you could run into a name like this: "Jose de la Madrid". There's just no possible algorithm that will always parse a name into the correct parts.

So if you really need to get first and last names separately, the best thing to do is use [@NameLookup](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/6607e1550e8e915f85256c54004c0bf0?OpenDocument) to retrieve the FirstName and LastName fields from the Domino Directory. Of course, that will only work if those fields are filled in, which isn't 100% guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This example returns "Mary Tsen" if the AUTHOR field in the document contains "CN=Mary Tsen/OU=Illustration/O=Acme":

`@Name([CN]; AUTHOR)`

Replace AUTHOR with the field name storing the document managers name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for ways to just format the name, as mentioned already you can use the [@Name](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NAME.html?lang=en) formula:

```
@Name([CN]; DocumentManager);
```

If you are looking for specific information on that user, you can use the [@NameLookup](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NAMELOOKUP_7699.html?lang=en) formula:

```
lastNameList := @NameLookup([ForceUpdate]; DocumentManager; "Lastname");
```

(where DocumentManager is the item that has your user's name, and "Lastname" is the value from the Person doc you are trying to retrieve);